# How to record audio and save at local system using htlml5?

Tags: html, ipad, audio, safari, mozilla

My basic requirement is let user to record his voice and wish to save that recorded audio at my local system. We do not wish to use flash player as we are planning to run at mobile also, our web application should run at desktop browsers, mobiles as well as at iPad?

I tried running sample suggested by at - http://webaudiodemos.appspot.com/AudioRecorder/index.html

- Windows 7 Firefox 26.0 - Not working
- Windows 7 Chrome Version 31.0.1650.63 m - Working
- iPad Safari - Not working

I need some solution that works fine on any browser at Windows, mobiles and as well as at iPad?

How can record audio and save them at local file system without flash player?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to capture audio in browser you need to use `navigator.getUserMedia` function.
As you can see from your example it uses in `initAudio` function(main.js file):

```
if (!navigator.getUserMedia)
            navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia;
```

More info about `getUserMedia` you can get from article on [html5rocks.com](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/). And as you [can see](http://caniuse.com/stream) `getUserMedia` works only in FF and Chrome.

What about to save any to local file system. Any browser don't give you permission to write something to filesystem, it's unclassified, but they have it implementation in sandbox by using `requestFileSystem`. More info about `requestFileSystem` you can get from [html5rocks.com](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/)

If you want to create modern HTML5 app - check often sites like [html5rocks.com](http://html5rocks.com) for new articles and read that already published.